# How to successfully load Ubuntu on Virtual box?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I was successfully able to install Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, and 20.01. The last two did not load at all. Ubuntu 16.04 did partially load in Virtual box, however, after selecting 'install ubuntu server'; it gave the following error message: "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU." Please help, I'm new to this and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Seems like you were NOT able to successfully install. Successful installs boot.

Comment: Using default Ubuntu desktop with GNOMEs Hell on VIrtualBox is a pain. Try Xubuntu, Lubuntu or MATE instead, they will install and work even with 2 Gb of RAM allocated for VM. Which CPU do you have?

Comment: Please check your releases; [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm and there was no Ubuntu release in 2020-January (20.01)

Comment: The error is quite explicit I feel; I get the  error "*This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU*" if I try and boot a *amd64* ISO on a *i386* box; ie. old pentium 4, pentium M, pentium D that is 32-bit only; ie. i686 class (& 32-bit only).  i386-i686 are 32-bit linux kernel cpu grades that Debian & Ubuntu have called all i386 on ISOs (small print gave clues as to minimum required; i686 was last of i386/32-bit x86 class).  Use an appropriate ISO that matches the CPU (or with virtual box change cpu setting on host)

Comment: The CPU that I have is i386, So Ubuntu 16.06 was able to load in Virtual box; the system recognized it and I was able to clear the error that stopped the installation. The problem is that I am now unable to edit/ move to the next step which is the customize the server I installed. So essentially, after the prompt to 'install ubuntu server' there is just a blank- black screen with no updated code nor information on the system I just created. I tried updating the storage, network, and the user interface; but the screen remains the same. I try to add a user profile but the system rejects it.

Comment: So, my question is, How do I get Virtual box to accept my customizations and to establish a user profile so I can complete the installation? In order to do administrative work as a normal user. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: There was no Ubuntu release in 2016-June (16.06) so I don't know what you're running; but all Ubuntu releases from that long ago (eg. 16.04) are in ESM and off-topic here, with support offered elsewhere.  I QA-tested using pentium 4/m/d or i686 only grade CPUs releases up to and including 19.04; so I see no reason to use an EOL/ESM release (18.10 & 19.04 are EOL too; the only *standard* support i386/i686 release available now is Ubuntu  18.04 LTS

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm